# type date directly in Angular mat-card

Tags: angular-material

I am developing an application for Human resources, in my application I used mat-calendar for dates, some of my users want to type the date directly in mat-calendar without using the click event to choose the year and month and day. I wonder if there is a method to use the two approaches

1. click one (click on year and month and day)
2. type the date directly like 23/11/2020 by example

thanks a lot for your help

```
<!-- date birth -->
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    required
    name="dateBirth"
    ngModel
    placeholder="Date Birth"
    [matDatepicker]="dateBirthCal"
  >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle
    matSuffix
    [for]="dateBirthCal"
  ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dateBirthCal></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<!-- ************* fin date Birth *************-->
```

Comment: So user can able to enter date? that's the problem or anything else?

Comment: yes that's the problem, I want to let the choice for the user, the first one to enter the date directly and the second by clicking the calendar, regards

Comment: Unable to understand! As you currently have mat-input then user can type `2020/01/01` or by clicking datepicker icon user can able to select date from datepicker!

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works as you said, but how I can use this pattern dd/MM/yyyy   regards

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` for user input or datepicker?

Comment: for writting a valid date now i am writin month/day/year and i want to change that to day/month/year

Comment: Can you share that existing code

Comment: when i type 27/09/1989 in calendar field I get a null value on submitting the form, but if i type 09/27/1989 I get : dateBirth: Date 1989-09-26T23:00:00.000Z how i can she my code?

Comment: using Stackblitz?

Comment: https://angular-xfjc51.stackblitz.io                       thanks